# Is making many tags for product description with same keyword hurting SEO?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, keywords, tags, products

I'm working on writing product description, my question is if I make many tags with the same keyword that included in product title, such that in each tag I write the main keyword with one LSI

for example:the main keyword is : Twitter followers
the tags are:

- increse Twitter followers
- rais Twitter follower
- Arab Twitter followers
- Asian Twitter followers
- Best website for rais Twitter followers

and another question: How many tags can I add to one product as maximum for SEO ?

Comment: Are these tags created with WordPress?  Is a tag page created for each of them?

Answer (score 1):

When you create tags for content that will be clickable on your website and visible to the viewers - as opposed to meta tags for SEO - you're doing it for the user. You have to ask yourself (or your web team), is this tag bringing any benefit to my website visitors?

For SEO purposes, I am a proponent of indexing category pages and noindexing tag pages, as in most cases tag pages can end up polluting the search results with similar, low level content that will not rank.

You also want to keep track of all the tags you're using, so you don't end up creating multiple similar tags (example: bar, bars, watering-holes) because that means your user won't see all the relevant content, which will now be split between several tags. I have seen many such cases of tag pollution among bloggers.

The technique you described makes your tags look spammy. If the rest of your content is good, you might not get penalized, but you'll still come off looking untrustworthy to the customer.

So when writing your product descriptions, make sure your tags accurately and usefully describe the product. Also, depending on your CMS, the product descriptions can end up inside your page's description tags. While description tags aren't indexed, they can help to lure (or turn away) a visitor who sees your page in the SERPs.